# Match partial strings from one sheet in another and copy corresponding values

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, match, gs-vlookup

I need to use data from Sheet 1 and compare it to data in Sheet 2. If the data, apart from its last four characters in Sheet 1, matches then I need corresponding data from Sheet 2 to be copied to Sheet 1. Maybe if there is a way to us a 50% match, it would work. For example:

```
Sheet 1
        A                                B                  C
Row 1  One-77 '11                                                    
Row 2  Veyron 16.4 '13                                           
Row 3  Corvette Z06 (C6) '06                              
Row 4  Nova SS '70                                                
Row 5  Enzo Ferrari '02                                           
Row 6  NSX Type R '92                                            


Sheet 2
        A                                B                  C
Row 1  One-77                                               Premium
Row 2  Veyron 16.4                                          Standard
Row 3  Corvette Convertible (C1)                            Premium
Row 4  Nova SS                                              Premium
Row 5  Enzo Ferrari                                         Standard
Row 6  NSX Type S                                           Premium

Sheet 1
        A                                B                  C
Row 1  One-77 '11                                           **Copies Premium**
Row 2  Veyron 16.4 '13                                      **Copies Standard**
Row 3  Corvette Z06 (C6) '06                                **Does Not copy, Leaves Blank**
Row 4  Nova SS '70                                          **Copies Premium**     
Row 5  Enzo Ferrari '02                                     **Copies Standard**      
Row 6  NSX Type R '92                                       **Does Not copy, Leaves Blank**
```

Keep in mind that in Sheet 1 the last 3 characters are the model year. Those numbers need to be there. They are not in Sheet 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description this should not suit but seems to for your sample:

```
=iferror(vlookup(left(A1,len(A1)-4),'Sheet 2'!A:C,3,0),"")
```

Comment: Your answer looks right but it doesn't work for me. The 0 seems to be throwing it off I believe.

Comment: =iferror(vlookup(left(E5,len(E5)-4),Sheet14!,E:H,4,0),"") I am getting the #ERROR and the ,0 has a red underline. If I hover over it it says Formula parse error.
I think I see my problem  the 'Sheet14!' did have the ' '

Comment: One more thing. Now that I have all the data I need from the other sheet. Sheet 2 is now ready for deletion. How can I keep the data that has been transferred.